# Neglecting terms in approximations where $x \gg y$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, physics, approximation

I mainly see this in physics, such as the proofs to a certain formula.
the question is asking for $$\left(x-\frac{y}{2}\right)^{-3} - \left(x + \frac{y}{2}\right)^{-3}$$,

but I used common denominators to reach $$\left(x + \frac{y}{2}\right)^3 - \left(x - \frac{y}{2}\right)^3$$ on the numerator. Anyways, the result should be $$3x^2y + \frac{y^3}{4}$$ as per usual, but given the condition $x \gg y$, the textbook seemingly ignores the $\frac{y^3 }{ 4}$ term. This is my main source of confusion as to when a certain term can be neglected, and I'd appreciate any explanation. If we were to approach it using negative *binomial expansion*, is the common practice to stop two terms in? (i.e $$\left(x - \frac{y}{2}\right)^{-3} = x^{-3} - 3x^{-4}\left(\frac{-y}{2} \right)$$

Comment: What's the denominator? When it says $x\gg y$ it can be helpful to think of it as $y/x \ll 1$.

Comment: In this case, wouldn't simply taking two numbers which satisfy $x\gg y$ and see how much each term contributes to in order to build some intuition?

Comment: If x and y are both smaller than 1, then $x^2y$ will be much bigger than $y^3$, so $3x^2y + y^3/4$ won't be much different from $3x^2y$

Comment: Yes, it is usual to carry only as many terms of a series expansion as necessary to reach the final result (or maybe one more as control). E.g., in computing the truncation error for a 2nd order Runge-Kutta method, one will usually truncate the Taylor expansion after the third (or maybe fourth) degree and not use 100 terms of it.

Comment: Late reply, but in introductory physics the usual convention is to stop at first order expansion since that's almost always enough to give the behavior of interest. The only common exceptions are if e.g. the first derivative of the function is zero, so you stop at second order instead. It's very rare that you'd need a third or higher order expansion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I properly read the question (please, start to use MathJax), you have
$$z=\frac{1}{\left(x+\frac{y}{2}\right)^3}-\frac{1}{\left(x-\frac{y}{
   2}\right)^3}$$ Let $y=kx$ and simplify to make
$$z=\frac 1 {x^3} \left( \frac{1}{\left(1+\frac{k}{2}\right)^3}-\frac{1}{\left(1-\frac{k}{2}\right)^3}\right)$$ Use binomial expansion or Taylor series or long division
$$(1+\epsilon)^{-3}=1-3 \epsilon +6 \epsilon ^2-10 \epsilon ^3+O\left(\epsilon
   ^4\right)$$

Replace $\epsilon$ by $\pm \frac k2$ to obtain
$$z=\frac 1 {x^3} \left( -3 k-\frac{5 }{2}k^3+O\left(k^4\right)  \right)$$ SInce $x\gg y$, $k\ll 1$ and $k^3$ is negigible.

So at first order
$$z\sim -3\frac k{x^3}= -\frac 3{x^4}$$

Is this clear for you ? If not, tell me.